# What data structure to use for heap in python

Tags: python, data-structures, heap

I was writing a custom heap implementation for `Udacity` course and needed a heap that would return a metric value for an element through both heap index and key of an element.

I have ended up with a list for a heap that contains `tuples (Metric, Key)`.

But to get the right element via key I had to create a separate map and maintain it's validity  for each change in the heap.

So in the end instead of having functions with two parameters like `heapup(heap, i)`, I had to pass map to all the functions - `heapup(heap, i, map)`.

I am wondering if there is a simpler way to do this through procedures, lists and dictionaries. Or Heap object will be required to hide the Map inside?

```
 def heapup(L, i, map):

    if i == 0: return i # we reached the top!
    if i >= len(L): return i
    if L[parent(i)] > L[i]:
       # print "going up"
        (L[i], L[parent(i)]) = (L[parent(i)], L[i])
        map[L[i][1]] = i
        map[L[parent(i)][1]] = parent(i)
        return up_heapify(L, parent(i), map)
    else:
     #   print "going down"
        if leaf(L,i): return i
        if one_child(L,i): return i # we could only come this way
        if L[i] > L[left(i)]: # compare with left child
            (L[i], L[left(i)]) = (L[left(i)], L[i])
            map[L[i][1]] = i
            map[L[left(i)][1]] = left(i)
            return left(i)
        if L[i] > L[right(i)]: # compare with right child
            (L[i], L[right(i)]) = (L[right(i)], L[i])
            map[L[i][1]] = i
            map[L[right(i)][1]] = right(i)
            return right(i)
```

I would like to get rid of map in that function but still be able to get items values from heap by their key which I now can do like this:

```
item = heap[map[key]]
```

**For example:**

if

```
L = [(3,'A'), (5, 'D'), (4, 'G') ...]
```

then

```
map = {'A':0, 'D':1, 'G': 2, ...}
```

so I can get a value of an element like this:

```
L[map['G']]
```

which will give me 4

Comment: I'm afraid I really don't understand what you're doing. What is `map` exactly? What does "Metric" mean in this context? Can you show the code you've created so far?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, but look at [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: please elaborate the question

Comment: basically L consists of tuples (x,y) where x - is a metric, and y is a key of the element. As you can see I have to update map every time I change position of elements in the heap. that will allow me to get element from the heap by Key like this: heap[map[key]]

Comment: @Blckknght metric is some numeric value that is used to sort elements in the heap

Comment: Could explain more clearly what operations your data structure needs to implement?

Comment: I need a heap from  which i can get a value for an element by both heap index and element's key. currently I do this by keeping tuples in the heap L like this: [(3,'A'), (5, 'D'), (4, 'G') ...] and having a map: {'A':0, 'D':1, 'G': 2, ...} so I could get value of the element like this: L[map['G']] which will give me 4.

Comment: Hmm, usually a heap doesn't allow you to look up anything but the smallest value. I don't think there will be an efficient way to allow random access by key. You may want something completely different than a heap.

Comment: @Blckknght actually I think this is just not required. I can also just push duplicate element to the heap and if it's value is less the of the duplicate one, it will just move close to the top of the heap.

Answer (score 3):

Use heapq http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html with description:

"This module provides an implementation of the heap queue algorithm, also known as the priority queue algorithm."